# How do unitary preserve inner products? Why is $\langle U x, U y \rangle = \langle x, U^\dagger U y \rangle$?

Tags: inner-products, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

On many links online [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313702/does-preservation-of-induced-norm-imply-unitarity), [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015770/norm-preservation-properties-of-a-unitary-matrix), [[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850242/how-do-unitary-matrices-preserve-the-magnitude-of-unit-vectors), etc. they mention the following:

$U$ is a unitary matrix, i.e. $UU^\dagger = U^\dagger U = I$, where $U^\dagger$ is the Hermitian conjugate of $U$.

Then,
$$\langle U x, U y \rangle = \langle x, U^\dagger U y \rangle$$

Why is this so?

Comment: The pure definition of the adjoint of $T$, $T^*$, is the operator such that the quality $$\langle v, Tw\rangle = \langle T^*v, w \rangle$$ holds for all $v,w$. The swap is only from what the definition of the adjoint is.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\langle u,v\rangle=u^\dagger v$, we generally have
$$\langle Tu,\,v\rangle=(Tu)^\dagger v=u^\dagger T^\dagger v=\langle u,\,T^\dagger v\rangle$$
for any vectors $u,v$ and any linear map $T$.

Comment: Why is $\langle u, v \rangle = u^\dagger v$? Shouldn't it only be the transpose, $u^Tv$?

Comment: @gust You need $\langle u,\,u\rangle\ge0$ for all $u$. What happens to the two proposed definitions we're comparing if I multiply $u$ by $i$?

Comment: @J.G. not completely sure; how does the positive definitivity apply here?

Comment: @gust $(iu)^\dagger=-iu^\dagger$, so $(iu)^\dagger iu=u^\dagger u$, but $(iu)^Tiu=-u^Tu$.

Comment: Just verify it using coordinates. What is the definition of the complex inner product you use?